# change redirection URL for not logged in user

Tags: symfony, symfony5

When I'm not logged in and I navigate to a secured route (/admin/page0 in this example), it redirects me to "/login" URL.

I want to change the redirection route to /admin/login

#Secured Route:

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/page0", name="admin_route")
     */
    public function adminIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'DefaultController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

#security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Admin:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        admin_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Admin
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin/
            #lazy: true #it means anonymous mode
            provider: admin_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AppAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: '%env(LOGOUT_REDIRECT_ROUTE)%'
                # where to redirect after logout
                target: default
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
                httponly: true
                samesite: strict
                secure: false
            access_denied_handler: App\Security\AdminAccessDeniedHandler
            access_denied_url: /

    access_control:
         - { path: ^/(|home|login|admin/login), roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY,    requires_channel: '%env(SECURE_SCHEME)%' }
         - { path: ^/admin,         roles: ROLE_ADMIN,                      requires_channel: '%env(SECURE_SCHEME)%' }
```

As you see I tried to do it by adding to my firewall:

```
    access_denied_handler: App\Security\AdminAccessDeniedHandler
    access_denied_url: /
```

But everytime I go to /admin/page0 it redirects me to /login :(

Answer (score 0):

In your firewall's authenticator guard, you have this method:

```
protected function getLoginUrl()    {        
    return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');    
}
```

You have just to modify the route name.